# Why Do You Need to Change Dispatchers in Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I've been going through [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#6) codelab to learn about coroutines. One thing  that still isn't clear to me is that why do we need to change dispatchers to ensure that we don't block the main/UI thread? If coroutines are light-weight threads, then why can't I invoke thread-blocking functions (whether they're suspending or not) within a coroutine when I'm already on the main thread?

The codelab explains that (in summary) if I write this code:

```kotlin
// Repository.kt
suspend fun repoRefreshTitle() {
    delay(500)
}

//ViewModel.kt
fun vmRefreshTitle() {
   viewModelScope.launch {
       _spinner.value = true
       repository.repoRefreshTitle()
   }
}
```

...then this won't block the main thread. `delay()` is a `suspend` function, so the coroutine created by `viewmodelScope.launch` will be paused until the 500ms passes. The main thread won't be blocked though.

However, if I refactor `repoRefreshTitle()` to the following:

```
suspend fun repoRefreshTitle() {
    val result = nonSuspendingNetworkCall()
}
```

...then that network call will actually be done on the main thread. Is that correct? I would have to change to another dispatcher to offload the work to an IO thread:

```
suspend fun repoRefreshTitle() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = nonSuspendingNetworkCall()
    }
}
```

I must be oversimplifying this somehow. Isn't the fact that I'm already in a coroutine enough? Why do I have to switch the dispatcher?

Comment: "However, if I refactor refreshTitle() to the following" -- in your first code snippet you have two functions named `refreshTitle()`. For clarity, at least in the question, it would be helpful if they had two different names. In this specific case, we do not know which one you rewrote. I'm guessing that it is the repository one.

Comment: Very good point, thanks for pointing that out. I've made some adjustments to more clearly differentiate the 2 functions.

Answer (score 5):

> The codelab explains that (in summary) if I write this code...then this won't block the main thread. delay() is a suspend function, so the coroutine created by viewmodelScope.launch will be paused until the 500ms passes. The main thread won't be blocked though.

Correct. However, what little real "work" there is in `delay()` will be performed on the main application thread, because the default dispatcher for `viewModelScope.launch()` is based on `Dispatchers.Main`.

> However, if I refactor repoRefreshTitle() to the following...then that network call will actually be done on the main thread. Is that correct?

Correct. `nonSuspendingNetworkCall()`, like `delay()`, will be run on the main application thread. In the `nonSuspendingNetworkCall()`, that's not a good thing.

> I would have to change to another dispatcher to offload the work to an IO thread

Correct. More specifically, you need to use a dispatcher that uses a background thread. For I/O, `Dispatchers.IO` is a common choice.

> Isn't the fact that I'm already in a coroutine enough? Why do I have to switch the dispatcher?

Because we do not want to do network I/O on the main application thread. `Dispatchers.Main` runs its coroutines on the main application thread, and that is the default dispatcher for `viewModelScope.launch()`. That's one of the reasons why, in a lot of what I write, I specifically write `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)` — that's more wordy (and technically slightly different than the default), but it is more obvious to readers.

Comment: I see, so the coroutine that's created in the `viewmodelScope`, it is still running on the main thread. It's not like it's a light-weight thread that's detached from the main thread. Is that correct?

Comment: @coolDude: Correct. If you have ever used `post()` on a `Handler` or `View`, running a coroutine on `Dispatchers.Main` is akin to `post()`-ing a `Runnable`. The `Runnable` still runs on the main application thread, just later.

Comment: I see, got it. Thank you for that clarification, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

When you run your code inside `viewModelScope` it doesn't mean your main thread won't freeze. It just ensures if you started work on MainThread and you are waiting for another thread to return a result, it won't block the main thread, e.g. calling an API with Retrofit and waiting to update LiveData in your ViewModel.

So Why do you need to change Coroutine Scope? (probably using `withContext`)

You start your work on Main Thread and switch to another coroutine for heavy work and easily get the result back on the main thread when the result is ready.

```
fun onSaveImageFile(source: Int, filename: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val isFileSaved = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        FileRepository.saveImageFile(source, filename)
    }
    toastViewModel.postValue(if (isFileSaved) "Image file saved!" else "Failed to save image file!")
}
```

Comment: I see, got it that totally makes sense now. I was under the impression that, since people say coroutines are like light weight threads, they'd be running as if they were detached from the main thread. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @coolDude Your welcome. read about Main Safty in Coroutines, that clears everything out. And also consider using RxJava if you haven't yet.

Comment: Using Retrofit is IO stuff, so that should also be called using Dispatchers.IO

Answer (score 0):

See this [documents](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) which describes that the `Dispatchers.IO` is specially designed for `I/O` operations where

```
viewModelScope.launch {

}
```

creates a coroutine block that is `lifecycle` aware and suitable for any asynchronous operation not specialized for `I/O` operation. When your `ViewModel` is destroyed then

```
viewModelScope.launch{
    // Invoke network suspend functions from repository
    // Or any kind of asynchronous operation
}
```

will be stopped and cancelled which will cancel this block

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // Invoke only I/O operations
}
```

too because `viewModelScope` keeps communication with that `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

You should not make your `viewModelScope` busy with `I/O` operations instead you should let another I/O specialized coroutine thread maintain that I/O operation and keep track from `viewModelScope`. This will make `viewModelScope` more light weight.